Can't copy-paste text from my latex pdf
I am using TexStudio to write my latex document, wich is using utf-8 encoding. All the pdf file generated can't be copy-paste. It seems like the pdf is generated as an image. Even when I change PDF reader I still have this issue. But when I put the same latex code or document on Overleaf, the texts in the pdf generated can be copy-paste.
I don't know what can be the issue. I tried the solution found here but unsuccessfully.
Here is a simple code that can't be copied in my generated PDF:
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-4] 
\end{document}


Welcome to TeX.SE, please mention which engine you used, i.e., PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX, etc.

show your log-file

With an up-to-date TeX distribution this should work out of the box, independent from the used engine. And because you are writing, that it also happens with other PDF viewers, TeXstudio is only the editor and PDFLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX is responsible for the resulting PDF. So this is surely independent from using TeXstudio or any other editor.

I am using PDFLateX engine, even with the up-to-date MikTEX 22.3 and TexStudio 22.3 versions, I still have this issue.

miktex 22.3 is not up-to-date, I have MiKTeX 24.4. But beside this: more important than your miktex version is your latex version so show your log-file.

My log file says : This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.25 (MiKTeX 24.1) (preloaded format=pdflatex 2024.8.8)  8 AUG 2024 14:34 entering extended mode  restricted \write18 enabled.  %&-line parsing enabled. **./Error.tex (Error.tex LaTeX2e <2023-11-01> L3 programming layer <2023-11-01> (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\report.cls Document Class: report 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class (C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/base\size10.clo File: size10.clo 2023/05/17 v1.4n Standard LaTeX file (size option) ) @UlrikeFischer

That isn't the newest but should be new enough. Put the full log and the tex file and the pdf file into some zip folder and upload it somewhere on the net.

I uploaded the files on my google drive.  Here is the link.

I can't access that.

@Pacifique  your link requires people to (1) login with a google account and (2) request access for that account since the file is not publicly available.

With the previewer of TeXstudio you can't copy and paste the text of the PDF file, but you can with any other pdf viewer.

Sorry @UlrikeFischer, is it okay if I put it on GitHub ? You can have access using this link.

@vipa, indeed with TeXstudio previewer I can’t copy paste. My problem is for other previewer. They can’t copy past too and I don’t figure out why. If you open the .pdf attached in the zip file sent on GitHub above you won’t be able to copy paste anything. But I’m sure if you recompile the ˋ.tex’ file in your TeXstudio it will work. The problem is it’s not working on mine, all my pdf got the same issue ever since. I’m trying to solve it but unsuccessfully.

your pdf is clearly broken. it maps all chars to U+00A0.  But I can't tell you why. The first thing that you should do it to check for updates in the miktex console (as user + admin if you have a multiuser installation) and to update everything.

Well, after updating MikteX the problem wasn't solved yet.
But I noticed that when I use XeLateX engine instead of PDFLateX, the generated pdf is copyable.
So I went through some stack exchanges about XeLateX producing odd symbols in PDF copy text found here. And I figured that cmap make PDF files copyable and searchable.
So adding \usepackage{cmap} line code changed everything and I can copy paste ... Here is the small file presented as an example.
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{cmap} %-- ADDING THIS LINE MAKE MY PDF COPYABLE
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[2-4] 
\end{document}


I'm glad you got it working, but this shouldn't be needed on an updated (or vaguely recent) system. copy-paste should 'just work' with pdftex.
